# setup webpack and docker for sharp library

Tags: docker, webpack, sharp

I am trying to use sharp (node image processing library) with docker and webpack. Everything works fine with my local environment on my own machine but when I am using docker things are not working and I get an error `Can't find module sharp`

In webpack configuration, I marked `sharp` as external dependency

```
externals: {
    sharp: 'sharp',
}
```

I bundle my server in a file `main.js` then I copy the file to the docker container and finally install `sharp` on my docker container. Here is my Docker file

```
FROM node:12.18.1

USER node
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH=$PATH:/home/node/.npm-global/bin:/home/node/.npm-global/lib
 
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/server
WORKDIR /home/node/server


ENTRYPOINT ["node", "main.js"]
COPY dist/ .
RUN npm install --global  --verbose --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp
```

I verified that `sharp` is actually installed in `/home/node/.npm-global/lib` so I am not sure why my bundle `main.js` can not find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was just a node path problem. So I have to set  `NODE_PATH` environment variable during runtime to `/home/node/.npm-global/bin:/home/node/.npm-global/lib/node_modules`. After doing that problem was solved and my bundle could locate sharp module